# Why is the acceleration of wedge and block equal like this

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

[image]

No friction at all anywhere. Let me explain the diagram in steps and the Q.

1. green colour let us start with. It represent a wedge on which there is mass of 10kg (red colour). That’s it the first picture.
2. dotted line in white represent when the block touches the bottom of the wedge.
3. represent the dotted yellow line which represents the direction of acceleration for 10 kg mass. Which is kind of like unknown or not in a symmetry.
4. Where the Q lies

The Dark yellow line represent displacements. Below one is AC I.e displacement of the wedge. Now , only thing in this Q what I don’t understand is that why is Displacement of mass 10kg BC even though the direction of acc for 10 kg is the dotted line.

If you wish to know why the dotted line , there is an example in my textbook which tells us that. Also , tells us that because of the dotted line kind of acceleration, we use pseudo force for solving such questions.

EDIT: Where a different concept and answer is also used.
[image]

Comment: Srijan is the wedge allowed to move?

Comment: @NMech Yes. Both wedge and the block is moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure below shall answer your question.

Moving from point B to C, the sliding force $F_S = mgsin\theta = ma$,

since no friction, $a = gsin\theta$,

and $\theta = Tan^{-1}(L_{BC}/L_{AC})$

[image]

Comment: But BC is vertical distance covered. What about the AB distance also covered ?

Comment: Ratio of distances would not match ratio of displacement right?

Comment: I feel you took BC because perpendiculardistscnce is always smaller.

Comment: Also , differentiation of distance is not velocity . So , is that the reason ?

Comment: @Srijan 1) AB = (AC^2+BC^2)^0.5, or AC/Cos(theta). 2) Why not, displacement is the distance traveled in the x & y axes, that is AC (horiz.) or BC (vert.). 3) I don't understand your question. 4) See this article for ds/dt, http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/glossary/calculus.html#:~:text=The%20quantity%20ds%2Fdt%20is%20called%20the%20derivative%20of,of%20s%2C%20and%20dt%20the%20differential%20of%20t.

Comment: Hmm K. I got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is another Q which has different answer with different concept.One has to wrong among both. Do check it in edit.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the acceleration the process is similar to this [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42875/find-the-acceleration-of-a-block-relative-to-incline-plane-in-non-and-inertial-f).

**For the inertial observer the angle of the acceleration ($\phi$) with the horizontal axis will be steeper than the angle of the inclined plane ($\theta$) (See red line in the kinetic diagram).**

[image]

As you can see on the inertial Frame you have:

- $a_A$ the acceleration of A with respect to the inertial frame. (the direction is not known)
- $a_W$ is the acceleration of the wedge with respect to the inertial frame. Since the wedge will be accelerating then the acceleration vector is pointing to the right.

The remaining vector $a_{A|W}$ is the acceleration vector with respect to the frame of reference of the Wedge. For a person standing on the Wedge as it is moving, then the **acceleration vector $a_{A|W}$ will be parallel to the inclined plane (it will form an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal plane)**.

So you have two vectors $a_W$ and $a_{A|W}$ , that you  know their directions. Therefore because of the equation:

$$\vec{a}_A = \vec{a}_W + \vec{a}_{A|W}$$

you can add up the accelerations and obtain $a_A$.  (*apology for the similarities with the other question but the process is exactly the same*)

The main difference know is that the motion of the wedge is dependent on the mass A, and on the angle $\theta$. So the diagrams for the wedge are

[image]

The resulting equations are the following
$$\begin{cases}
- N_{1x} = -m a_{Ax}\\
- mg + N_{1y} = -m a_{Ay}\\
 N_{1x} = m a_{W}\\
-  N_{1y} + N_2 - mg = 0\\
a_{Ax} = a_{Wx} + a_{(A|W)x}
a_{Ay} = 0  + a_{(A|W)y}
\end{cases}$$

which you can solve for the equations.

Comment: Hmm K. Thanks a lot. I got it totally.

Comment: Srijan, my result is not same as the other answer. Just saying. To be more explicit, I don't agree with the other answer.

Comment: Yeah. I’m solving the final equations. But your answer looks fine to me.

Comment: I have got the basic idea of your answer. Also , if you mean the above answer , where do you not agree ?

Comment: I’ll be going to sleep now. Any Q of anything , ask me. Write it here and I’ll answer it in a few hours.

Comment: The angle $\theta$ is the angle with the inclined plane. However, for the inertial observer the angle that the acceleration of the mass forms with the horizontal plane ($\phi$) will be steeper.  I don't want to comment further, so  I suggest you have a talk with your teacher to clean this up.

Comment: I feel you mean the direction of acceleration (yellow dotted line) I wrote above in my Q is what you are also thinking. Is it correct ? If not , I’ll check with my teacher too.

Comment: If you are thinking what I am then yes, you are right. We need to use a non inertial frame to solve for acceleration of the block. But the thing we did is that we took displacements( shortest distance travelled) which has no relation with what is the direction of the block. It just wants shortest distance from the origin. Therefore , It is the perpendicular from point B. So , we find is the ratio of acceleration for block and wedge actually.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the mass will travel only downwards? (From B to C in the other answer?) Because, it will not.

Comment: I know it won’t but in terms of shortest distance , that is BC right.

Comment: @SrijanM.T I am not sure what you mean by the last comment or what is the use of the shortest distance in this case? Maybe I misunderstood the question in the first place.  I assumed that you wanted to find the direction of the acceleration (mainly from the title, because I couldn't understand what does Q mean in the body of the question).

Comment: After finding ratio of shortest distance , you differentiate it to get acceleration ratio.

Comment: @SrijanM.T What do you mean by the ratio of the shortest distance (With respect to what)?  could you update your question to show what you mean? I've never came across the this technique. Also, could you describe what Q is?

Comment: If theta = 37 degrees. Then , tan 37 = Disp of mass / Disp of wedge = 3/4. Then , differentiating wrt time. We get acc of mass / acc of wedge.